# How to scrape data from YouTube with Cheerio?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, cheerio

```
client.on("message", async function(msg) {
  var request = require('request');
  var cheerio = require('cheerio');
  request('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVRhrcoG6FOvHGKehYtvKHg/videos', async function(err, resp, body) {
    if(err) throw err; else {
      let $ = cheerio.load(body);
      let views = $('#subscriber-count');
      console.log(views.html());
    }
  })
})
```

This logs `null` value to console. I tried about 6-7 different things but I couldn't get it to work.

I want to scrape the subscriber count of a Youtube channel via Request&Cheerio. Any idea? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

USE official you tube API for this, dont parse page. [API DOCS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections)

```js
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key
```

```js
    client.on("message", async function(msg) {
      var request = require('request');
      var cheerio = require('cheerio');
      request('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key', async function(err, resp, body) {
        if(err) throw err; 
        let data = JSON.parse(body);
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get channel data from YouTube with Cheerio, because YouTube dynamically loads content on the page via JavaScript. To get what you want, you need to use some browser automation, e.g. [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). In the code below I show you how you can do this (also check [it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-channel-subscriber-with-NodeJS#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const channelLink = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVRhrcoG6FOvHGKehYtvKHg/videos";

async function getSubscribersCount() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(channelLink);
  await page.waitForSelector("#contents");
  const subscribers = await page.$eval("#subscriber-count", (el) => el.textContent.trim());
  await browser.close();
  return subscribers;
}

getSubscribersCount().then(console.log);
```

If you want to scrape the description, comments or other info from the video page, there's a [web scraping YouTube video page with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-video-page-with-nodejs/) blog post that shows that.